# how to get the sequence number of a kinesis record when consuming using pyspark and spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

we are using pyspark and spark streaming to consume records from a kinesis stream
the code looks something like this :

```
  streams = [
        KinesisUtils.createStream(
            ssc,
            app_name,
            stream_name,
            endpoint_url,
            region_name,
            InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON,
            conf["stream"]["checkpoint_interval"],
            decoder=gzip.decompress,
        )
        for _ in range(number_of_streams)
    ]

    ssc.union(*streams).pprint()
```

the output has a data column and some metadata columns that were added to the payload.

the metadata column is empty.

the question is if we should get metadata columns by default : such as sequence number and partition key.

and if not is there a way to get them using pyspark?
using spark 2.4.4 emr 5.27 and spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11-2.4.4.jar

thanks.